# PHP MYSQL Automate Create Value

Tags: php, mysql

i have code like

```
$quota = 100;
$quotaperclass = 25;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $quota/$quotaperclass ; $x++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO classroom (name) VALUES ('A')";
    for ($y = 0; $y <= 25 ; $x++) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO classroomstudent (studen_id, class_id) VALUES ('', 'A')";
    } 
}
```

I want if quota per class 25, total quota div quota per class. in my case result is 4 and then automated create 4 class like A, B, C, D and then add every student to the class.

my question is. 
how to change value name automated like

```
loop 1 is A 
loop 2 is B
loop 3 is C
etc
```

and how to add every student into class automatically.

thanks

Comment: `$value = chr(65+$x)`. Only works up to `$x=25`.

Comment: So are you trying to create 100 students divided across 4 classes? Or better stated X number of students divided into Y number of classes based on maximum of Z students per class? Why insert empty stings for id values?  This seems problematic. Why names like 'A', 'B', 'C' for classes rather than something meaningful.  If you just want to divide into Y number of classes, I would think integer value would suffice rather than applying arbitrary letters values (what happens after you exceed 26 classes?)

Comment: id auto increment. or do you have better code? *code edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$range = range('A', 'Z');

$quota = 100;
$quotaperclass = 25;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $quota/$quotaperclass ; $x++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO classroom (id, name) VALUES ('', '".$range[$x]."')";

}
```

Comment: @MochamadSaepulM *now* - This was posted 6 mins. prior to that. If this works, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$c = 'A';
for ($x = 0; $x <= $quota/$quotaperclass ; $x++) {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO classroom (id, name) VALUES ('', '$c')";
 $c++;
}
```